# add custom field values as tags in Liferay user portlet

Tags: tags, liferay, liferay-6.2

I have a custom field called Skills in liferay 6.2 user profile (i.e when you click on My Account->Details section). For now this Skills field accepts multiple text values and shown as a plain text entry. I want to show each skill being entered as a Tag. Is there any available UI component to perform this task? I checked on Tags management on Liferay documentation. They suggest to add tags from Admin->content section. However i want to create tags on the fly as user enter values on Skills.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want the Skills the user enter to be created as tags in the portal.

For that you would need to create a Custom `CreateAccountAction` for creating user accounts.

This is done using Liferay Extension Plugin project too extend the `addUser()` method in liferay.

then inside the extended `addUser()` method you add logic to create `AssetCategory`, `AssetVocabulary` and Tags

here is an example of a possible method to create the Skill tag

```
protected AssetCategory addAssetCategory(long userId,
        long parentCategoryId, String title, long vocabularyId,
        ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {

    Map<Locale, String> titleMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();

    setLocalizedValue(titleMap, title);

    return AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addCategory(userId,
            parentCategoryId, titleMap, null, vocabularyId, null,
            serviceContext);

}

protected AssetVocabulary addAssetVocabulary(long userId, String title,
        ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {

    Map<Locale, String> titleMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();

    setLocalizedValue(titleMap, title);

    return AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.addVocabulary(userId,
            StringPool.BLANK, titleMap, null, null, serviceContext);
}
```

Make sure you use `serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true)` and `serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true)` before calling the methods to ensure that the proper permissions are gotten

Comment: Create the ServiceContext like this                                        
 `ServiceContext serviceContext =
    ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(BlogsEntry.class.getName(), portletRequest);`

Comment: Actually i used Bootstrap tags input plugin to solve these issue at that time. Thanks for these comments,  i will check it later if we need these requirements again

Answer (score 0):

my approach is to use liferay ui asset tag selector. It provides UI component to assign and display tags

```
<label>Skills</label>
        <liferay-ui:asset-tags-selector
            className="<%= User.class.getName() %>"
            classPK="<%= selUser != null ? selUser.getUserId() : 0 %>"
        />
```